# Using Greece-issued multiple entry tourist Schengen Visa for conference in Czech Republic

Tags: schengen-visas, multiple-entry, greece, czech-republic, conferences

last month I visited Greece for tourism, for which I have a multiple entry Schengen tourist visa.

Next month I have a conference coming up in Prague. Could I use the same visa to enter Czech Republic and attend the conference?

Thank you!

Comment: What annotations on your visa? How many total days were you given to spend in the Schengen area? I’m not referring to the visa validity period.

Answer (score 4):

Both Greece and Czech Republic [are members of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Current_members). Schengen membership implies freedom of travel within the Area for those holding a valid visa for one of the member countries.

Since yours is multiple-entry, and you have already used it to enter the issuing country, you should be perfectly fine to enter Czech Republic, as long as your visa is still valid on the dates of your travel, and you have not exceeded the allowed number of days for your stay (the maximum is 90 days, but yours may vary).